# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _REQUEST in /var/www/data/system/address/index.php on line 34

Tags: php-5.5, joomla3.4

Hi i got after a Update to PHP 5.5.9 a Problem with my PHP Code. Can some one help me ?

}

```
public function update($_REQUEST) {
    $form = this->createForm('', @$_REQUEST['aID']);
    //$form->showQuery = true;
    $form->saveExistingEntry();

    return '<h1 class="go">Gespeichert</h1>';
}
```

Comment: $_REQUEST is an auto-global. You don't pass it in the parameters. It is global. Just remove it from the parameter list of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this error is saying is that you are attempting to name a variable in the function $_REQUEST. That is a reserved variable name. You cannot create your own variable with that name. But, you say, I don't think I'm that!? Yes. By making a parameter of your function named $_REQUEST, you are saying: Within this function, I have a variable that I will name $_REQUEST. So, you are attempting to create a variable named $_REQUEST.

So, the fix...

```
public function update() {
```

That avoids naming a variable $_REQUEST. But, how can you access $_REQUEST inside the function? It is an auto-global. It exists everywhere. Therefore, your attempt to access $_REQUEST['aID'] will work even though you didn't put $_REQUEST in the parameter.

Comment: I changed it, i got the next failure... i'm sorry... i'm realy a noob in PHP.   Now i got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in Line 35

Comment: Because you have "this" without the "$". It should be "$this". In PHP, all variables begin with $.